# How to make a cell show the text of another random cell?

Tags: random, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a spreadsheet list, which includes a cell (`E1`) that chooses a random number like so:

```
     C   | D |     E
   ------+---+------------------
1 |      |   |=RANDBETWEEN(1,99)
```

I would like to make another cell show the text in column C, row of random number from `E1`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried already. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "make another cell show the text in column C, row of random number from E1. How can I accomplish this?" What do you want displayed in column C? Your sentence is not making sense to me. What 'text' are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to retrieve the value from column c,

```
=index(c:c, e1)
```